# Are reoccuring cold sores, canker sores, & easy bruising symptoms of a poor immune system? Or just low on Vitamin C?

Tags: canker-sores, cold-sores, vitamin-c, bruising-bruise

**Are reoccurring cold sores, canker sores, & easy bruising symptoms of a poor immune system? Or just indications that an individual could be low on Vitamin C?**

I could be Vitamin C deficient, but I don't think that I'm so deficient that I've developed scurvy or anything...

Also, I do have fibromyalgia and borderline Lupus so are the cold sores/canker sores/bruises all parts of the that fun diagnosis?